# Putty connection failing from Home network

Tags: linux, putty

Im connecting to a server using Putty. I have a connection time-out every 2 minutes if I don't use it. I don't have the same issue while connecting from my office network using the same laptop.

Settings changed:

```
Seconds between keepalives
```

Comment: What value have you changed the "Seconds between keepalives" to, in PuTTy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your SSH servers settings. It sounds like it's disconnecting you if there is inactivity after a set period of time. This are typically the settings you need to play with:

```
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
```

They're in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. These are commented out in my setup, you can check if they're un-commented and try commenting them out or changing their values.

Comment: Thanks..I dont have the same problem from my office network..Same laptop..same settings

Comment: @user1050619 - turn up the session logging in PuTTY to see why it's disconnecting you would be the next thing to look into. Also is there a firewall on your home network that you're passing through?

Comment: After your changes it started working..Thanks..

Answer (score -1):

The server is probably not disconnecting you, it is most likely a router between you and your server, which explains why on different networks (especially the same network as the server) you don't have an issue.

You can fix this on the server side by adding `TCPKeepAlive yes` to your config (/etc/ssh/sshd_config on debian). Possibly you might need to mess with ClientAliveInterval as well if it's set to too high a value.

On the client side you can check `Enable TCP keepalives (SO_KEEPALIVE option)` under Connection in PuTTY (it is off by default).